# Allow sound effect to layer every time it is pressed?

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, avfoundation

everyone. I am currently experiencing an issue and will try to be as basic as possible explaining it using an example.
I am tinkering with an app that plays an audio effect that is about 3 seconds long when the user taps the button but here is my issue.

This is what it currently does: 
press button -> starts playing 3 second audio but if i press the button again before the 3 second audio ends it does nothing

THIS IS what i want it to do: 
press button - > starts playing 3 second audio but if i press the button again before the 3 second audio ends for the audio to reset and play from the beginning again.

I am using AVFoundation to play the sound. I dragged the audio file into my project 
assigned the identifier in my header file using:
AVAudioPlayer *soundclip;

Then used this method to be able to attach the file to the identifier:

```
- (AVAudioPlayer *)setupAudioPlayerWithFile:(NSString *)file type:(NSString *)type
{
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:file ofType:type];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

NSError *error;

AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url     error:&error];

if (!audioPlayer) {
NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);
}

return audioPlayer;
}

Then used it like so in view did load:

    soundclip = [self setupAudioPlayerWithFile:@"filename" type:@"wav"];
```

and to play the audio:

```
[soundclip play];
```

Can someone help me figure this bug out? I have been searching for a while. Please

Comment: What part of AVFoundation are you using to play the audio? AVPlayer? Can you give a code sample?

Comment: AVAudioPlayer *click;

Comment: then using this method:

Comment: - (AVAudioPlayer *)setupAudioPlayerWithFile:(NSString *)file type:(NSString *)type
{
    
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:file ofType:type];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    
    
    NSError *error;
    
    
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    
    
    if (!audioPlayer) {
        NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);
    }
    
    
    return audioPlayer;
}

Comment: and then simply [click play]; to play the file

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but you need to create a new `AVAudioPlayer` for every sound you want to play. Are you calling the `setupAudioPlayerWithFile:type:` method more than once in your view controller? Or are you only creating one `AVAudioPlayer` for the class?

Comment: By the way, if this is right, I'll post it as an answer so you can accept it.

Comment: only 1 for the audio file.

Comment: Basically what i am trying to do is for example: I press the button it plays the 2 second audio BUT if i want to press the button again before the 2 second audio ends for it to play over the previous one. Make sense?

Comment: the same audio file with the same button.

Comment: Or have it reset the previous action and start the audio file play over.

Comment: anyone have any ideas?

Comment: @dvtrjosh, it looks like you tried to edit your question, but weren't logged in at the time. If you log in, you don't need to get approval to edit your own question.